# Deleting table view row data from data source

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a data source which holds different lists like in apples notes app.
When the user taps on one row in the ListViewController (all lists) a second ViewController is presented which holds only the data of this list.
The whole data source is in a plist and the key is the list name:

```
    var items = [Items]()
    var showItems = [Items]()

    func loadPlistData() {

    // Connect to plist and get the data
    if let plist = PlistHandler(name: "Items") {
        getPlist = plist.getMutablePlistDict()!

        // Load the items into the table view data source
        for i in 0..<getPlist.count {
            listItems = (getPlist.object(forKey: "Item\(i)") as! NSArray) as! [String]

            if listItems[1] != "" {
                items.append(Items(list: listItems[0], name: listItems[1], shop: listItems[2], price: listItems[3]))

                if listItems[0] == listName  {
                    showItems.append(Items(list: listItems[0], name: listItems[1], shop: listItems[2], price: listItems[3]))
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Unable to get Plist")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

So what I'm doing here is to load the whole data source into the items struct and the data for the table view into the showItems struct. 
When I add a new item this will be added to both structs which works fine. But when it comes to deleting I run into a problem:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        showItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        // Ho to delete the correct item from items here?
        // Update the plist
        itemPlistUpdate()

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
    }
}
```

So how can I delete the correct item from items here? Or is there a better way where I don't need to create two data sources?

Comment: are there any error messages generated?

Comment: no, the code above works fine because I'm not deleting from items yet.

Comment: what do you mean by the comment how to delete the correct items from here ?
I can see you are already deleting items a line above

Comment: items is holding all list items (from all lists), showItems holds the items of the current list. I'm deleting from showItems which is easy because this is the list in the active TableViewController. To delete the correct item from items I need an index ..

Comment: does your Items struct/class have anything unique in them like a product id or something?

Comment: no. I'll try the solution below

Comment: solution below will work, but break at the condition which I'm trying to tell you.. if you ever had two items with same name or properties and they dont have anything unique, you will land up deleting the wrong element.

Comment: Maybe there was a misunderstanding regarding the uniqueness of the strings in the items/showItems struct. Please have a look at my solution. Do you thing this is not safe enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating an array of keys and an editKey for the item which will be edited later.

```
var items = [Items]()
var showItems = [Items]()
var keyArray = [Int]()
var editKey = Int()
```

While populating the showItems struct every item gets the correct key with the help of the array.

```
// Load the data from plist
func loadPlistData() {

    // Connect to plist and get the data
    if let plist = PlistHandler(name: "Items") {
        getPlist = plist.getMutablePlistDict()!

        // Load the items into the table view data source
        for i in 0..<getPlist.count {
            listItems = (getPlist.object(forKey: "Item\(i)") as! NSArray) as! [String]

            if listItems[0] != "" {
                items.append(Items(list: listItems[0], name: listItems[1], shop: listItems[2], price: listItems[3], remark: listItems[4]))

                if listItems[0] == listName  {
                    showItems.append(Items(list: listItems[0], name: listItems[1], shop: listItems[2], price: listItems[3], remark: listItems[4]))

                    keyArray.append(i)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Unable to get Plist")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

So the table view will be filled with the content of showItems. When it comes to deleting I use the corresponding key to delete the item from the items struct.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return showItems.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ItemCell

    let myItems = showItems[indexPath.row] as Items
    cell.myItems = myItems
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        showItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        let key = keyArray[indexPath.row]
        items.remove(at: key)
        keyArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        // Update the plist
        itemPlistUpdate()

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    editKey = keyArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

The editKey will be used in the following segue method:

```
@IBAction func editItemDetail(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let editItemViewController = segue.source as? EditItemViewController {

        // Save the edited item to the struct and update the plist
        if let changedItem = editItemViewController.editedItem {
            items.remove(at: editKey)
            items.insert(changedItem, at: editKey)
            // Update the plist
            itemPlistUpdate()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [index(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688966-index) to find the index of the object in items and then deleting it

Here a sample code with index:

```swift
class Person {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}


var people = [Person]()
people.append(Person(name: "foo"))
people.append(Person(name: "bar"))
let toDelete = Person(name: "lorem")
people.append(toDelete)
people.append(Person(name: "sic"))
people.append(Person(name: "quam"))



let index = persons.index(where: {$0 === toDelete})
print(index) // print 2
```

Comment: good idea, but in this case I need a unique name or key - which I don't have yet. I think this is not a 'safe' way.